# Keras Custom Layer : 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a custom layer with Keras with Tensorflow backend in order to process images.

The process fails when using Keras but works with tensorflow (partially).

To understand better the issue I implemented an Identity layer and had the same issue :

> 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'

Here is my code :

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.python.keras import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras import  optimizers

import cv2

from keras.engine.topology import Layer # This Layer does not work

#
# USE KERAS IMPLEMENTED INTO TENSORFLOW TO MAKE IT WORK
#

#from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.engine.base_layer import Layer

import numpy as np


class Identity(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(Identity, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):

        super(Identity, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!


    def call(self, x):

        return x


    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

        return tuple(input_shape)




height = 12
width = 18
channels = 3

image_original = cv2.imread("./predict_base.png")
input_data = np.zeros((2, 12, 18, 3))
input_data[0] = image_original
input_data[1] = image_original

input_shape = (height, width, channels)

input = Input(shape=input_shape)
output = Identity()(input)

# add the model on top of the convolutional base
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)

adam = optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam)

model.summary()
image = model.predict(input_data)

cv2.imshow("result", image[0])
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Whereas a more complex layer works in using directly tensorflow, it fails to compute the output shape correctly.

If I introduce an error in the output shape computation such as :

```
def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    output_shape = []
    output_shape[0] = input_shape[0]
    output_shape[1] = input_shape[1]
    output_shape[2] = input_shape[2]
    output_shape[3] = 4               #Here is the error I added

    return tuple(output_shape)
```

The output shape is still the same, tensorflow does not compute the output correctly.

Do you have any idea how to fix this ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Important: how are you inspecting the output shape?

Comment: @DanielMöller I use `print(model.summary())`

Comment: @AlixL Is there a reason why you use tensorflow keras for layers instead of keras layers since you want to use keras Layer class?

Comment: Notice that when you do `return x` in call, the true output shape is the input shape. So tensorflow may actually be calculating it correctly despite you having set it wrongly in the layer.

Comment: @Y.Luo as explained the keras layer gives an error (try to replace the tensorfloz keras layer by the keras one)

Comment: @DanielMöller The output shape is calculated by Keras and not by Tensorflow.

Comment: @AlixL Is the error "'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'" or another one? I don't have your image. But if I use everything from just Keras, I can see `model.summary()` fine.

Comment: You should be using everything from a single package: `from keras.layers import *`, `from keras.models import Model`. Mixing things may cause strange behavior. But hey, if the keras layer gives an error and you actually want to cause an error, that's correct behavior, no?

Comment: @Y.Luo Indeed ! The issue comes from the fact that I mixed tensorflow and Keras layers. Everything with Keras works fine. Thank you