# Keras MobileNet cannot previous saved model h5 file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I just trained a MobileNet model with keras (using tensorflow as backend).
When the training was finished I saved the model with

```
# serialize weights to HDF5
model_with_weights = os.path.join(model_dir, "model.h5")
model.save(model_with_weights)
print("Saved model to disk")
```

Now I would like to re-load the same model...
so I tried this (model is in the right directory)

```
model = load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={
                       'relu6': keras.applications.mobilenet.relu6,
                       'DepthwiseConv2D': keras.applications.mobilenet.DepthwiseConv2D})
```

But I got this error and I don't know what to do in order to load the previous trainied model.

```
File "load_model.py", line 79, in <module>
    'relu6': keras.applications.mobilenet.relu6})
  File "/home/seba/Projects/venv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/saving.py", line 241, in load_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/seba/Projects/venv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/saving.py", line 318, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/seba/Projects/venv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 64, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/seba/Projects/venv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 173, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/seba/Projects/venv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/network.py", line 1098, in from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "/home/seba/Projects/venv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/network.py", line 1056, in process_node
    layer(input_tensors[0], **kwargs)
  File "/home/seba/Projects/venv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 606, in __call__
    previous_mask = _collect_previous_mask(inputs)
  File "/home/seba/Projects/venv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2834, in _collect_previous_mask
    mask = node.output_masks[tensor_index]
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'
```

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Are you trying to use both tensorflow keras and the keras together? I just [solved one same error in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259158/keras-custom-layer-node-object-has-no-attribute-output-masks#comment87540259_50259158). Can you upload all your imports or a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible?

Comment: Can you better explain what you mean? I thought that there were only one keras.

Comment: You can import keras related api from either `tensorflow.python.keras` or from `keras` directly. I'm not sure what you did in your code. Based on the stack trace, you seem to have both `tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/...` and `keras/engine/...`.

Comment: Yes you are right...I probably mixed both...which ones shold I use? Probably the tensorflow ones as I leverage with extimator and tfrecord format as input files

Comment: They are similar but not the same. That's why it may cause problems. As for now, I'd say try either one and see if that solves your problem first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciated your help! I will try tonight :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170807/discussion-between-seba-and-y-luo).

Comment: Thanks a lot using all tf.keras api solvede the problem :)